# Freeze rows and columns using xlslib library ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xls, ios-frameworks, xlslib

I want to freeze columns and row panels of excel file which i create using xlslib library in iOS which contains headers os if anyone have idea about it then please provide the code or method used to freeze columns or rows using xlslib.

I have already used locked() method of xlslib but it doesn't work at all.